# Excel pick a value from an array

Tags: excel

Is there a formula in Excel to pick a random value from a list of values? For example, I want a cell to randomly pick its value from `"Yes, No, Maybe".`

```
Answer
Yes
No
Maybe
Yes
```

Comment: This question is off topic, as it is not about programming.

Comment: Ok, sorry, did not know about this. Can't fix downvote unless edited though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),"Yes","No","Maybe")
```

**EDIT#1:**

The distribution of results can be "weighted" (up to a point).  Consider:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),"Yes","Yes","No","Maybe")
```

This will produce **twice** as many *Yes*'s as *No*'s or *Maybe*'s

This is a little crude..............Also note that are limitations on how many items *CHOOSE()* can handle!

Comment: What if you wanted more "Yes" in the result? Is there a way to say, I want 90% to be "Yes"